# How to customize the layout (maxLines) of a CheckBoxPreference?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences, android-styles, android-preference-v14

I am using the following `settings.xml` to inflate my `SettingsFragment` extending `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/settings_category_title_general">

        <android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="@string/settings_default_value_lorem"
            android:key="@string/settings_key_lorem"
            android:summary="@string/settings_summary_lorem"
            android:title="@string/settings_title_lorem" />

    </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

The `summary` text is cut off after **four lines** which is defined in `com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1` in `res/layout/preferences.xml`:

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
    android:maxLines="4" />
```

The layout inspector shows the `summary` id as well:

[image: Preference layout]

To overwrite the setting I defined the following styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppPreferenceTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppPreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/AppPreference</item>
</style>

<style name="AppPreference" parent="@style/Preference">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/settings_item</item>
</style>
```

and created a copy of the original layout file `preferences.xml` named `settings_item.xml` which overwrites `android:maxLines="4"`.

However, the style is **not applied**. I added a `background` color to the `summary` view to check this.

---

## Related

- [Building an Android settings screen (Part 4): How to use a custom layout for the Preference fragment](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-an-android-settings-screen-part-4-9558029827b7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc of the `Preference` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference#Preference(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20int)):

> Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style. This
>   constructor of Preference allows subclasses to use their own base style
>   when they are inflating. For example, a `CheckBoxPreference`
>   constructor calls this version of the super class constructor and
>   supplies `android.R.attr.checkBoxPreferenceStyle` for
>   `defStyleAttr`. This allows the theme's checkbox preference
>   style to modify all of the base preference attributes as well as the
>   `CheckBoxPreference` class's attributes.

So change your styles to:

```
<style name="AppPreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">@style/AppPreference</item>
</style>

<style name="AppPreference" parent="@style/Preference.CheckBoxPreference">
    <item name="layout">@layout/settings_item</item>
</style>
```